# laravel-file-manager not working with google-cloud-storage

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage, file-manager

I am trying to get laravel-file-manager to work with Google Cloud Storage. I can't get it to display the preview. If I choose properties from the mini-menu and click "Get URL" I do get the correct url but the preview is not showing the bucket's url.

[image]
I have added the gcs to filesystems:

```
'gcs' => [
    'url' => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name',
    'driver' => 'gcs',
    'key_file_path' => base_path(env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null)), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
    'key_file' => [], // optional: Array of data that substitutes the .json file (see below)
    'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'your-project-id'), // optional: is included in key file
    'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'your-bucket'),
    'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', ''), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
    'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
    'apiEndpoint' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_ENDPOINT', null), // set storageClient apiEndpoint
    'visibility' => 'public', // optional: public|private
    'visibility_handler' => null, // optional: set to \League\Flysystem\GoogleCloudStorage\UniformBucketLevelAccessVisibility::class to enable uniform bucket level access
    'metadata' => ['cacheControl'=> 'public,max-age=86400'], // optional: default metadata
],
```

I am obviously doing something wrong but can not figure out what nor can I find any documentation or examples of using this page with the cloud disk.

In case it matters I am using

- "alexusmai/laravel-file-manager": "^3.0",
- "spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.2",
- Laravel 9

Answer (score 1):

Probably your "bucket" on google cloud storage has access set access as "uniform".

When you try to upload file on GCS usisng default "spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage" configuration that I see on your question you need to change one config linie.

The following option in 'gcs' filesystem config -  "visibility" is set to "public". This option will not work with "uniform" bucket access type.

To fix this issue set this option:

```
'visibility' => 'noPredefinedVisibility'
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace the `bucket-name` with the actual bucket name

```
'gcs' => [
    'url' => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name', // Put actual bucket-name
 ];
```

Run the below command to publish the config file
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=fm-config`
Edit the below code:

```
'roots' => [
    [
        'driver' => 'gcs',
        'path' => '/',
        'url' => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name', // Put actual bucket-name
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I read the documentation but thanks